# Is there any way to find Dynamic memory size like sizeof facelity?

Tags: c++, c, malloc, heap-memory

I am looking for something which give me size which taken by str character pointer.

```
int main()
{
    char * str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    int size = 0;
    size  = /* library function or anything use to find size */
    printf("Total size of str array - %d\n", size);
}
```

I want prove that give memory is 100 bytes.
Is any one have any idea about this ?

Comment: use a `std::string` or `std::vector` instead

Comment: Yes, learn how to use C++'s `std::string`s, whose `size()` gives you the number of characters in the string, any time you want. Do you actually intend to use C or C++? No C++ program ever needs to use `malloc` or any of the C library functions.

Comment: There's a fair chance the memory block you were given is actually more than 100 bytes, not that the program would be allowed to touch the rest.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++. And please don't use C-style casts either.

Comment: the right size is right there ==> char \*str = malloc(**sizeof(char) \* 100**). If you are going to use it, save in a variable... `size_t saved = sizeof (char) * 100; char *str = malloc(saved); /* ... use saved ... */ free(str);`

Comment: I am not new in this language I know size is already there but i want the way in c language so that i can get the size in between the program which one is allocated by malloc.

Answer (score 2):

A raw pointer only knows it points to a single element of it's type. If that thing it points to happens to be part of an array, the pointer doesn't know and there's no way to get that information from it.

You want to instead use types that *do* know their size, like for example; `std::string`, `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

1. The C and C++ standards do not provide a way to get, from an address, the amount of memory that was requested in the call to `malloc` that returned that address.
2. Some C or C++ implementations provide a way to get the amount of memory that was provided at the given address, such as `malloc_size`. The amount provided may be greater than the amount that was requested.
3. If the memory contains a string, which is an array of characters terminated by a null character, then you can determine the length of the string by counting characters up to the null character. This function is provided by the standard `strlen` function. This length is different from the space allocated unless, of course, the string happens to fill the space.

Answer (score 0):

There is no (good, standard, portable) way to tell from a pointer value alone whether it's the first element of an array or not, nor how many elements follow it.  That information has to be tracked separately.

If you're writing in C++, don't do your own memory management if you can help it. Use a standard container type like `std::vector` or `std::map` (or `std::string` for text).  If you *must* do your own memory management, use the `new` and `delete` operators instead of the `*alloc` and `free` library functions, and wrap a class around those operations that also keeps track of how many elements have been allocated (which, like `std::vector` and `std::map`, is returned via a read-only `size()` method).